# win-interactive How to bind class to an existing Div

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

Hi I want to dynamically bind a class name to an existing div inside an itemTemplate when the data source gets populated.

Heres the html code for winJs

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div data-win-bind="class:classFromServer"></div>
        </div>
```

But this is not happening when I am binding the class in data source. the click event front he previous question does get execute but cannot bind class. Any work around or other way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a bit of code wrong Here :)

it will be `<div data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div data-win-bind="className:classFromServer"></div>
        </div>`

class will be actually classame for Binding